# VueJS Store pattern with get & set

Tags: vue.js, state

I have a small store (following the state pattern on VueJS (not VUEX)).

It essentially looks like this

```
export default {
    get selectedPartner() {
        return localStorage.getItem('selectedPartner');
    },

    set selectedPartner(item) {

        localStorage.setItem('selectedPartner', item);
    },


    clearFilters() {
        localStorage.removeItem('selectedPartner');
    }
}
```

In my .vue component I am now trying to bind to it like so

```
    data: function() {
      return {
        // Other stuff here...
        selectedPartner: filterStore.selectedPartner,
      }
    },
```

Now, when it draws the component, the getter is actually properly called.
When i change the value in the component, it does not update the store...

I do realise that doing it like this (in localStorage) is awfully close to VUEX.
But chose for this approach to grasp state in its most simple form first, before getting into VUEX.

Many thanks

Comment: Does the `set selectedPartner` function get called?

Comment: No it does not :-(

Answer (score 1):

Use `computed` instead of `data`:

```
computed: {
  selectedPartner: {
    get() { return filterStore.selectedPartner; },
    set(item) { filterStore.selectedPartner = item; }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does work, but it kinda defeats the purpose. I wanted to have 2-way binding between my store and my data() properties. is this not do-able?

Comment: this poses one additional problem, the computed properties are cached... :( so they dont re-evaluate to what you'd expect when changed